# Can't get phpmyadmin to list multiple servers

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get the server drop-down to appear in the login screen but it won't, I've added both servers in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php but so far can only get it to work with one at a time. If I increment the variable `$i` it just leads to a semi-blank screen with no tangible database information on it, if I comment `$i` out it, it defaults to the second server.

The first server is localhost, the second is a docker instance, the relevant content of config.inc.php is

```
if (!empty($dbname)) {
    /* Authentication type */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'db on the pc'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
    /* Server parameters */
    if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;

    if (!empty($dbport) || $dbserver != 'localhost') {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $dbport;
    }
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    /* Select mysqli if your server has it */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    /* Optional: User for advanced features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbpass;
    /* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';

    /* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
     * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

    /* Advance to next server for rest of config */
    $i++;
}

//$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'second_db'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '172.18.0.1:3307'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user';   //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'pass';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

As you can see, I've commented out `$i` as a temporary solution so it's now defaulting to the second server (172.18.0.1). It's worth noting I have valet installed and noticed some interesting behavior ever since which is that phpmyadmin is no longer accessed by me using localhost/phpmyadmin but phpmyadmin.test which I did by using a valet command inside the phpmyadmin folder. My question is how do I get both servers to show on the login screen?

Edit: If I put the second server inside the if clause, after `$i++`, the login screen will default to the first instead and ignore the second

Comment: Check this example: https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/bionic/universe/all/phpmyadmin/4:4.6.6-5/file/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/config.manyhosts.inc.php Alternatively, don't use `$i` at all and set that number manually (taking note that it MUST start at 1, not 0)

Comment: I see you sorted this out, but if you want to go back to it I would suggest dumping the entire $cfg array to examine that, it seems something isn't getting set properly in your code and looking at the contents of the variable should help clear up some of the mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the configuration to as it was allotted [here](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/bionic/universe/all/phpmyadmin/4:4.6.6-5/file/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/config.manyhosts.inc.php) and I now have the server drop-down and issue is resolved.

```
$i = 0;
// The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use $cfg['Servers'][0].
// You can disable a server config entry by setting host to ''.
$hosts = [
'172.18.0.1:3307',
'localhost'
];
foreach($hosts as $host) {
$i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']     = $host;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']     = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']   = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']     = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']        = 'mysql';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = FALSE;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']      = 'pma';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']      = 'pmapass';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']        = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']     = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']  = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']  = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']    = 'phpmyadmin';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable']    = 'pma_bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info']       = 'pma_table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']     = 'pma_table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']        = 'pma_pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']      = 'pma_column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history']  = 'pma_history';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
}
$i++;
```